# Context Free Grammar for Tamarian Language

Tags: context-free-grammar, nlp

I am trying to figure out the CFG for [Tamarian](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tamarian_language) language. I think for English, the starting symbol `S` usually starts with the production rule `S -> NP VP`. Which means we can divide a typical sentence into parts of `Noun Phrase` and `Verb Phrase` and derivation goes from there.
My question is, what would be a CFG or at least the first production rule for the Tamarian language. Some of the example sentences are below:

'Sinda his face black his eyes red'
'Darmok and Jalad at Tanagra'
'Picard and Dathan at Eladrel'
'Marab with sails unfurled'

Answer (score 1):

Each of the example sentences is (what we would call) a noun phrase, so the first production rule should probably be `S -> NP`.

Comment: Thanks @Dyck. At least I thought something similar. Now, the first sentence makes me most confused. What would be a proper split for it? Somethinglike `NP -> NP JJ` ?

Comment: Well, that depends on how you define `JJ`. Grammatically, I'm not sure what `his face black his eyes red` is. Maybe an 'absolute phrase'?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see sufficient information for answering your question in the link you provide. The "sentences" you provide are not really sentences of Tamarian. "Zinda, his face black, his eyes red" means "anger or conflict"; so it is just a lexical entry. I cannot see how these blocks are combined to form sentences in our sense.

Phrase structure grammars were designed for languages of our type, where sentences can be hierarchically structured into phrases in some way. But when the level of words (like "anger" or "conflict") is reached, these grammars usually do not further break down these units (though in some cases the flection suffixes or prefixes can be split from the lexical core of the word). So, if the phrase "Zinda, his face black, his eyes red" has just the meaning of a word, a phrase structure grammar would probably not analyze it further.

As I have said, I have not seen an explanation on how elements that you cite are combined in Tamarian to express, for example a causal relation, to express that the anger is mine ("I am angry") etc. But as long as we do not know, what phrases look like (if they exist), there is no point in a phrase structure analysis.